# RewriteRule at htaccess wrong redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

ive this rules  at htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^warcraft$  www.site.com/forumdisplay.php?f=480 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

issue happend when redirect warcraft  its redirect to

```
http://www.site.com/home/site/public_html/www.site.com/forumdisplay.php?f=480
```

any tip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to redirect it to http://www.site.com/forumdisplay.php?f=480

 If so put it in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^warcraft$  http://www.site.com/forumdisplay.php?f=480 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the full URL including protocol in your rule, in this case `http://www.site.com/.....`